# R is showing an error of" Object not found' but it is present in the data set

Tags: r, data-analysis

I am trying to plot a graph using a data set, one of the column is named as ' internet.users; but upon typing this query:

```r
qplot(data = demo, y = birth.rate, x = Internet.Users)
```

The following error is coming:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Internet.Users' not found

Kindly provide a solution with an explanation as to why this is happening; because few months ago I used this same query it runs smoothly unlike now. Thank You

Comment: Please edit your question and give an short example of your data using `head(demo)`.

Comment: i dont know how to enter the R output;head(demo)  in its correct format on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transformed your data

```r
data <- read_table2("No Country.Name Country.Code Birth.rate Internet.users Income.Group
                    1 Aruba ABW 10.244 78.9 High_income
                    2 Afghanistan AFG 35.253 5.9 Low_income
                    3 Angola AGO 45.985 19.1 Upper_middle_income
                    4 Albania ALB 12.877 57.2 Upper_middle_income
                    5 United_Arab_Emirates ARE 11.044 88.0 High_income
                    6 Argentina ARG 17.716 59.9 High_income")
```

Your question is simply a typo since R is case sensitive. Try

```r
qplot(data = demo, y = Birth.rate, x = Internet.users)
```

instead of

```
qplot(data = demo, y = birth.rate, x = Internet.Users)
```

Comment: Problem Solved. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: One more Problem Upon entering this query. '''qplot(data = cov , x=customer_name, y = Reedem Time)''' why this error is appearing:'''Error: unexpected symbol in "qplot(data = cov , x=customer_name, y = Reedem Time"''' Kindly solve this problem too

Comment: Make sure `y` is really named `Reedem Time`. In this case you have to put Reedem Time in backticks `.

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept an answer, not necessarily mine. [Accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Done. Thanks, once again, Martin